Is it possible to bridge to native code from package?
I have project. In my project I use some packages from pub.dev. One of the packages has some Android (and iOS) native code prepared to be called by method channel. Can I call this native code by creating bridge in my project?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
